# How to access Windows 7 start search with Python?

Tags: python, search, windows-7

I would like some of my scripts to have an access to Windows 7 search with Python.

Possibility to get results I get when i go into *Search for programs and files* in windows is what I am interested in.

Few clues are available for me right now. Should I use win32 api?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use the following resource to figure out what you want to query:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb266517%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

If I understand that page correctly, you may be able to use an OLE-DB connection to query the search index using SQL. I believe you can use [pyAdo](http://pyado.sourceforge.net/) for this task.

On the other hand, the following link shows a method of calling `explorer.exe` itself to do the query:

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/1c7349d7-7ea9-4e2b-8061-1a4d36e4619c/calling-windows-search-programatically-in-windows-7?forum=windowsdesktopsearchdevelopment

It's example goes like this:

```
explorer.exe "search-ms://query=ref123"
```

If you went that route, you could use Python's subprocess module.